# jqgrid - horizontal scrollbar - position - after paging - from left to right

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, scrollbar, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

Consider the following scenario:

JqGrid is loaded.

Since data is wide, it has horizontal scroll bar.

scroll to right.

Now, click on next page(paging)

Next page is displayed.

But the scroll bar is in right side, that is from where at previous page the scroll bar position maintains.

*Our requirement is to have the scroll bar at left after paging independent of previous page scroll bar positions.*

I searched over the net and not found any article / demo for this scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `scrollLeft` of bDiv inside of `onPaging` for example. The corresponding code could looks like in simplified form as the following:

```
onPaging: function () {
    var bDiv = this.grid.bDiv;
    setTimeout(function () {
        bDiv.scrollLeft = 0;
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very much. Working fine as expected. Great..)